# Enabling and disabling of FieldEditors

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have a doubt related usage FieldEditors in Plugin development. I have a preference page which basically consists of some StringFieldEditors, booleanFieldEditors, RadioGroupFieldEditors etc.

The problem I'm facing is as follows:

I have a booleanFiledEditor called "Full Details". The code for this is as follows:

```
BooleanFieldEditor fullDetails = new BooleanFieldEditor("fullDetails", "Full Details", org.eclipse.swt.SWT.NONE, getFieldEditorParent()); 
addField(fullDetails);
```

Once the user checks this boolean field, the StringFieldEditors which follow this booleanFieldEditor should get enabled. Otherwise they should remain disabled. The code for other StringFieldEditors are as follows:

```
StringFieldEditor machineName = new StringFieldEditor("machineName", "Host name", getFieldEditorParent()); 
addField(machineName);

StringFieldEditor ipaddress = new StringFieldEditor("ipaddress", "IP Address", getFieldEditorParent()); 
addField(ipaddress); 

StringFieldEditor cpuinfo = new StringFieldEditor("cpuinfo", "CPU Info", getFieldEditorParent()); 
addField(cpuinfo);
```

It would be very helpful if anyone can give some pointers as to how this can be done.

Comment: what about using `StringFieldEditor.setEnabled()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setPropertyChangeListener` method of the boolean field editor to perform an action when the field changes. Something like:

```java
fullDetails.setPropertyChangeListener(new IPropertyChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event) {
        boolean newValue = ((Boolean) event.getNewValue()).booleanValue();

        // Enable/disable other fields

        machineName.setEnabled(newValue, getFieldEditorParent());
        .... other fields ....
    });
```